# CMD completion for path executables

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Let's assume a folder `C:\Convert` that contains a `convertImage.exe`. After putting `C:\Convert` onto %PATH% I'd like to be able to use completion in CMD for convertImage.exe so that I only have to type convertI... to get to the executable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not from a Command Prompt no, this doesn't even work for the like of ping.exe etc

Auto completion in Command Prompt only works within the directory, so if you do cd c:\convert then you can press c then tab and you'll get it filled.

If you add the path to the Path variable under system variables then you can click Start -> Run and type just covertImage.exe and it will work

Answer (score 15):

## Clink

- Powerful Bash-like line editing from GNU's Readline library. Readmore on Readline's keyboard shortcuts.
- Superior path completion (TAB).
- Paste from clipboard (Ctrl-V).
- Support for the completion of executables/commands, and environment variables.
- Undo/Redo (Ctrl-_ or Ctrl-X, Ctrl-U)
- Improved command line history.

  - Persists across sessions.
  - Searchable (Ctrl-R and Ctrl-S).
  - History expansion (e.g. !!, !, and !$).
- Scriptable completion using Lua.

https://mridgers.github.io/clink/

Comment: +1 I wish I could give you more upvotes. Dunno how I never found this before now.

Comment: This is amazing, and I'd never heard of it!

Comment: 10 / 10 госпаде

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open regedit.exe and navigate to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor

2. Add two REG_DWORD  values if they do not exist: **CompletionChar** and **PathCompletionChar**.
   Edit their values to "9" (sans-quotes) and restart the computer.

After reboot, try to use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to autocomplete.

Other than that there is no way for command to use an automatic autocomplete.